# R Rename Group Column

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

```
data=data.frame("student" = c(12,12,12,75,75,75,31,31,31,31,46,46),
"newID"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4))
```

I have 'data' with 'student' and want to generate 'newID' that keeps the integrity of the 'student' column but starts with 1,2,3, and so on and so forth.

Comment: use `lag` function to detect where you have a difference then `cumsum` to get you newID

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(data$student))` should do it